# Facebook Open Graph - Share Dialog not appearing from Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Implementing Share feature on web application.

While the code below works with your favorite desktop and mobile browsers (Share Dialog shows up when clicking on the Share button), it wont work (the Share Dialog doesn't show up) when the web application is opened via Facebook Android Application (by clicking the Website URL from a post and it open's up from the website)

```
FB.ui({
       method: "share_open_graph",
       action_type: "og.shares",
       action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                    "fb:app_id": "my_app_id",
                    "og:url": "url_of_my_app",
                    "og:title": "my_app_title",
                    "og:description": "my_app_desc",
                    "og:image": "display_image",
                    "og:image:width": "600",
                    "og:image:height": "350"
            }
       })
}, function (response) {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb when using FB.ui is to not use FB.ui inside a Promise success callback. Facebook Application is blocking pop-ups when called inside a successful return of Promise.